# Gradle fail to find plugin is present in the central plugin repository

Tags: java, ssl, gradle

I'm trying to build a Gradle project (this, to be exact: https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/ ) and the build fails with the following error:

```
$ ./gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\bravih6\coding\simple-binary-encoding\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'io.freefair.javadoc-links', version: '5.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.freefair.javadoc-links:io.freefair.javadoc-links.gradle.plugin:5.1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

However, looking at the Gradle central repository reveals that the package and version are present:
[image: gradle central does contain io.freefair.javadoc-links version 5.1.0]

My only hypothesis for what is going wrong is that the corporate VPN I am on is replacing the certificates between Gradle and the repository and screwing up SSL. However, I've not been able to verify this (nothing in the error message indicates that it has failed to connect to the repo) and I'm not able to test this by disabling SSL (I've searched, but can't find such an option).

Does anyone know:

1. Is this how Gradle behaves if it cannot connect due to SSL issues?
2. Is there a way I can disable SSL verification in Gradle?

Comment: Never seen SSL errors manifest themselves like that. But you could be right in that it might be your corporate VPN making problems. You could try running the build with `-d` (maybe pipe the output to a file) and search for "freefair". It should say "Performing HTTP GET ..." or something similar in the output. If the first request to the plugin repository goes well, it will likely redirect to another repository where the artifact is located. Try the same URLs in a browser and see what you get back. Maybe that can help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: It gives me this URL: https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/freefair/javadoc-links/io.freefair.javadoc-links.gradle.plugin/5.1.0/io.freefair.javadoc-links.gradle.plugin-5.1.0.pom
I can access that in a browser, but my suspicion is that the browser may be allowing signings by a root certificate that Gradle is not aware of.